# Laravel 404 Not Found - But Route Exists

Tags: laravel

Hello im trying to get information about user on my view.

Here is my UserController

```
public function getUser(Request $request, $id)
{

  $user = User::findOrFail($id);

  return view('admin.user', ['user' -> $user]);

}
```

here is my web.php

```
Route::get('admin/user/{id}', "UsersController@getUser");
```

and my user view

```
@extends('admin.layouts.app')

@section('contents')

<h1>User {{ $user }} </h1>

@endsection
```

I am trying to display user information in this view, like name etc, but im recives 404
Not Found page. What im doing wrong. Im using Laravel 6

Comment: What is the URL you are visiting?

Comment: admin/user/1 or admin/user both don't work

Comment: Well `admin/user` does not match the route you've shown us so we can't comment on that.  But for `admin/user/1` - does user ID 1 exist?

Comment: oh god, such an error, everything works, there was no user with id 1 in the database

Comment: also 
`return view('admin.user', ['user' => $user]);`

Answer (score 3):

404 error may refer to a User not being found, since you have a findOrFail() query.  It may have nothing to do with your routes.

Just double check with:

```
 php artisan route:list
```

just to make sure the route is being registered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you firstly use any **prefix** for this route.For this it will give you an error.To check route list.

```
php artisan route:list
```

it will give you all route.
And Here you don't need (Request $request) because here you just need the id.it not the problem..i give you just this suggestion

```
public function getUser($id)
{

  $user = User::findOrFail($id);

  return view('admin.user', ['user'=> $user]);

}
```

why you use '-> ' you should use '=>'